# realtime speech to text with vosk and streamlit

Tags: vosk

i am trying to build a realtime offline speech recognition system using vosk and streamlit.
i completed the vosk normal statement recognition but it doesnt working in live . when i am using threading in python it gives main thread error and also sometimes it gives utput but it doesnt print continously recognition function doesnt work until transcribe function is printing. anyone help me to implement that speech to text in live and also when i want to connect this to streamlit it doesnot printing the output but when i  tries with the speech recognition api i cann see output in streamlit but not in vosk .please solve this problem .
i am pasting my code here please suggest any changes and references.

i tries with this code to live speech to text and in streamlit.

```
import pyaudio
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
from queue import Queue
import streamlit as st
import time

recordings = Queue()
CHANNELS = 1
FRAME_RATE = 32000
AUDIO_FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
SAMPLE_SIZE = 2
model = Model(model_name="vosk-model-small-en-in-0.4")
rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, FRAME_RATE)
mic = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = mic.open(rate = FRAME_RATE,channels = CHANNELS,format = AUDIO_FORMAT,input=True,frames_per_buffer=8192)
stream.start_stream()
class recognition:
    def speech(self):
        self.frames = []
        while True:
            self.data = stream.read(20000)
            self.frames.append(self.data)
            recordings.put(self.frames.copy())
            self.frames = []
    def transcribe(self):
        while True:
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(b' '.join(recordings.get())):
                self.text = rec.Result()[14:-3]
                #cased = subprocess.check_output('python vosk-recasepunc-en-0.22/recasepunc.py predict vosk-recasepunc-en-0.22\checkpoint', 
                #shell=True, text=True, input=self.text)
                st.write(self.text)

sr = recognition()
record = Thread(target=sr.speech)
record.start()
time.sleep(2)
transcribe = Thread(target=sr.transcribe)
transcribe.start()
```